# How to install fenics in Ubuntu using PIP for a particular python environment?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, fenics

I want to install [fenics](https://fenicsproject.org/) in Ubuntu 20.
First I made a python environment using:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

Then inside the folder I want to make an environment I open a terminal and use:

```
python3 -m venv myproject
```

`myproject` is the name of the environment I made.

I then activate my environment:

```
source myproject/bin/activate
```

To install fenics for this particular environment while I activated the environment, I use:

```
pip install fenics
```

I verify the installation using `pip list` which returns:

```
Package        Version       
-------------- --------------
fenics         2019.1.0      
fenics-dijitso 2019.1.0      
fenics-ffc     2019.1.0.post0
fenics-fiat    2019.1.0      
fenics-ufl     2019.1.0      
mpmath         1.1.0         
numpy          1.19.4        
pip            20.0.2        
pkg-resources  0.0.0         
setuptools     44.0.0        
sympy          1.7.1
```

I try to import fenics using:

```
python -c "import fenics"
```

But I get the error below stating there is not fenics module:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fenics'
```

What is the problem? Hopefully, after successful installation of fenics, I can install Spyder and other python packages and will be able to use fenics inside spyder.

**Edit**
I want to install fenics in a python virtual environment.

Comment: It will probably only work a python3.5 interpreter.

Comment: I was not even able to install fenics with `pip` on `Ubuntu 20.04` outside an `venv`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `fenics` is just a meta-package and it does not contain any library that you can use in your Python code.

Quoting from the [README](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/fenics/src/master/) for the `fenics` project :

> This package contains a single file, setup.py, that allows all of the FEniCS Python components to be installed from PyPI using pip:
>
> ```sh
> pip3 install fenics
> ```

Actual use of the library is done via

```py
import ffc
```

All different components are under this package. For example, `fenics-fiat` is available as `ffc.fiatinterface`.

Comment: Thanks! I can import fenics the way you mentioned, but I cannot run the examples from fenics. It seems it has problem with the `UnitSquareMesh` becuase it cannot find it.
The example: https://github.com/hplgit/fenics-tutorial/blob/master/pub/python/vol1/ft03_heat.py

Comment: There are two version of `fenics`. The one you have installed via `pip` is the one which is the "older" version which is in a BitBucket repo, the newer, actively developed version is on Github on which I guess the tutorial is based, and can be installed via Ubuntu as per [this official page](https://fenics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#debian-ubuntu-packages)

Answer (score 0):

[Fenics library](https://pypi.org/project/fenics/) of python

If you have installed `pip` than you have to use `pip install fenics`. If you have installed `pip3` than `pip3 install fenics

[image]

[image]

I have already installed both.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Install pip for Python 2 with:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing `pip3 install fenics`,write `python3 -c import ffc` to import it. If this works, it has been imported. It is called ffc, not fenics

Comment: I guess you meant ``python3 -c "import ffc"``